# Multiple Nested Inner Joins: not all records are shown

Tags: sql-server

I have difficulty joining two tables that look like the following:

- The main table PMEOBJECT which has a unique key named OBJECTID and
  has in total 12768 rows.
- Then I want to join PMEOBJECTVALIDITY on it which has an n:1 relationship with PMEOBJECT, since it has more rows,
  because it saves the changes over time of PMEOBJECT (i.e. when a certain object is not
  valid anymore), this one has 12789 rows (meaning only 21 objects
  changed over time). However, I only want to have the current last
  VALIDFROM date shown in the query. This all works fine.
- Then the trouble starts when I want to join PMEOBJECTDIMENSION, which has an
  n:1 relationship with PMEOBJECTVALIDITY and has 36737 rows in total.

  ```
          SELECT 
              PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID
              ,PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.VALIDFROM
              ,PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.DIMENSION2_
          FROM PMEOBJECT
                  LEFT JOIN PMEOBJECTVALIDITY
                      ON PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.OBJECTID = PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID
                      AND PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.DATAAREAID = PMEOBJECT.DATAAREAID
                      INNER JOIN(
                          SELECT 
                              OBJECTID,
                              MAX(VALIDFROM) AS NEWFROMDATE,
                              MAX(VALIDTO) AS NEWTODATE
                          FROM PMEOBJECTVALIDITY B
                          GROUP BY OBJECTID
                          ) B 
                          ON PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.OBJECTID = B.OBJECTID 
                          AND PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.VALIDFROM = B.NEWFROMDATE
                  LEFT JOIN PMEOBJECTDIMENSION
                      ON PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.OBJECTVALIDITYID = PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.RECID
                      AND PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.DATAAREAID = PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.DATAAREAID
                      INNER JOIN(
                          SELECT 
                              OBJECTVALIDITYID,
                              MAX(VALIDFROM) AS NEWFROMDATE_2
                          FROM PMEOBJECTDIMENSION C
                          GROUP BY OBJECTVALIDITYID
                          ) C
                          ON PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.OBJECTVALIDITYID = C.OBJECTVALIDITYID 
                          AND PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.VALIDFROM = C.NEWFROMDATE_2
  ```

Results in query per step:

- SELECT PMEOBJECT: 12768 rows
- LEFT JOIN PMEVALIDITY: 12789 rows
- INNER JOIN PMEVALIDITY: 12768 rows
- LEFT JOIN PMEOBJECTDIMENSION: 36737 rows
- INNER JOIN PMEOBJECTDIMENSION: 12729 rows

I want the end result again to have the same 12768 rows, I don't want any ObjectId to be left out.

What am I missing here?

Kind regards,
Igor

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a great place to start. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Following might help:

from PMEOBJECTDIMENSION onwards:

```
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.OBJECTVALIDITYID, PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.DATAAREAID
            FROM PMEOBJECTDIMENSION
            INNER JOIN(SELECT OBJECTVALIDITYID, MAX(VALIDFROM) AS NEWFROMDATE_2 
                FROM PMEOBJECTDIMENSION C 
                GROUP BY OBJECTVALIDITYID
                ) C
            ON PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.OBJECTVALIDITYID = C.OBJECTVALIDITYID 
            AND PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.VALIDFROM = C.NEWFROMDATE_2
        )X
        ON X.OBJECTVALIDITYID = PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.RECID
    AND X.DATAAREAID = PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.DATAAREAID
```

and select the distinct records if duplicates present.

Answer (score 1):

The `INNER JOIN`s are filtering out records- what you want is that the `LEFT JOIN` table (`PMEOBJECTVALIDITY` and `PMEOBJECTDIMENSION`) should only include records that have at least a match on the `INNER JOIN` queries (alias `B` and `C`). You can accomplish this with by nesting the `INNER JOIN` with the `LEFT JOIN`, generally done as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    INNER JOIN C
    ON B.ID = C.BID
ON A.ID = B.AID
```

Now `B` is `INNER JOIN`ed on `C` and will only contain records that have a match in `C`, but will preserve the `LEFT JOIN` not remove any records from `A`.

In your case, you can simply move the `ON` clause from the `LEFT JOIN` to the end of the following `INNER JOIN`.

```
    SELECT 
        PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID
        ,PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.VALIDFROM
        ,PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.DIMENSION2_
    FROM PMEOBJECT
            LEFT JOIN PMEOBJECTVALIDITY
                INNER JOIN(
                    SELECT 
                        OBJECTID,
                        MAX(VALIDFROM) AS NEWFROMDATE,
                        MAX(VALIDTO) AS NEWTODATE
                    FROM PMEOBJECTVALIDITY B
                    GROUP BY OBJECTID
                    ) B 
                    ON PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.OBJECTID = B.OBJECTID 
                    AND PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.VALIDFROM = B.NEWFROMDATE
            ON PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.OBJECTID = PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID
                AND PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.DATAAREAID = PMEOBJECT.DATAAREAID --here it is!
            LEFT JOIN PMEOBJECTDIMENSION                    
                INNER JOIN(
                    SELECT 
                        OBJECTVALIDITYID,
                        MAX(VALIDFROM) AS NEWFROMDATE_2
                    FROM PMEOBJECTDIMENSION C
                    GROUP BY OBJECTVALIDITYID
                    ) C
                    ON PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.OBJECTVALIDITYID = C.OBJECTVALIDITYID 
                    AND PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.VALIDFROM = C.NEWFROMDATE_2
           ON PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.OBJECTVALIDITYID = PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.RECID
                AND PMEOBJECTDIMENSION.DATAAREAID = PMEOBJECTVALIDITY.DATAAREAID --I'm here
```